# progress bar in notification

Tags: android, progress-bar, notificationmanager

i try to put the progress bar into the notification. but the problem is the system will not respond for few seconds and progress bar stuck at beginning once it's started, please take note that even the progress bar is get stuck-ed but the file is still downloading.

Below is the code, please guide me how to deal with the progress bar.

```
public class StaffChoice extends Activity {
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progress = 10;

    Intent MyI;
    PendingIntent MyPI;
    NotificationManager MyNM;
    Notification notification;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private void startDownload() {
        String url = "http://www.domainurl.com/3d.png";     //this is not a valid url
        DownloadFileAsync dfa = new DownloadFileAsync();
        dfa.setActivity(StaffChoice.this);
        dfa.execute(url);
        }

       public void onTaskCompleted() {
           dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
       }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staffchoices);

        MyI = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaxAppsAct.class);
        MyPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyI, 0);
        MyNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StaffChoice.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Downloading...", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.staffchoices);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgIcon, R.drawable.save);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvText, "Downloading...");
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress, false);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(42, notification);        
        startDownload();
        }

    public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        StaffChoice activity;
        private boolean completed;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
            }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MaxApps");
            boolean success = false;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
                }
            if (!success) {

            } else {

            }

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MaxApps/3d.png");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
            notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            completed = true;
            notifyActivityTaskCompleted();
            }

        public void setActivity(StaffChoice activity){
            this.activity = activity;
            if (completed) {
                notifyActivityTaskCompleted();
                }
            }

        private void notifyActivityTaskCompleted() {
            if (null != activity) {
                activity.onTaskCompleted();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Logcat:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you shouldn't use AsyncTask inside a thread.

To show notification, in your AysnTask, add following code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
     notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
 }
```

**Update**: error in the logcat look like this (the dismiss dialog cause error): 
http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/

You can try this:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {

private void startDownload() {
String url = "http://www.domainurl.com/3d.png";
DownloadFileAsync dfa = new DownloadFileAsync();
dfa.setActivity(YourActivity.this);
dfa.execute(url);
 }

   public void onTaskCompleted() {
dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
   }

   public void dismissDialog(int id){
    //...
   }

   public void showDialog(int id){
    //...
   }

public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

YourActivity activity;
    private boolean completed;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    activity.showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    // nothing change
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
    notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        completed = true;
        notifyActivityTaskCompleted();

}
}

public void setActivity(YourActivity activity){
           this.activity = activity;
           if ( completed ) {
            notifyActivityTaskCompleted();
           }

private void notifyActivityTaskCompleted() {
if (null != activity) {
    activity.onTaskCompleted();
}

}
}
```

When you use *publishProgress* in *doInBackground*, it should update the progress to notification

Comment: ok, i removed the thread and do actually what u said(see #1 for the update), now how to run the DownloadFileAsync's class?

Comment: @melvintcs: From my answer, just call new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url); (put it into onCreate or button click event to sync download) You should read the AsyncTask 's document: developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i have update my first post with my full code, attached with logcat. have a view. problem is still the same, progress bar stuck, but the file is still downloading

Comment: activity.showDialog() instead of showDialog() and should show the ERROR part in logcat

Comment: i will update this code again, i need to remove "DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS" , this is the code to display the progressbar on the UI not notification which i dint include